# Measuring scalability of the web app hosted on cloud

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, hdfs, elgg

I have developed a social networking site using the elgg framework and I am hosting it on amazon cloud (Amazon EC2, the free tier micro instance service) and thus develop a benchmark for it.I am creating around 200 columns describing each user (most of them dummy) and after that I should create around a million users with each users profile updated with some data.This is done to reflect the image of big data.When hosted on cloud we should measure the cloud's performance based on a query and an update action for all users. The problem is how to create so many users? Which tool would be optimal to choose? Done this, I should also consider storage on a file system(HDFS) and do the same with some modifications (The output should be a row and the input should be an unstructured data). 
For elgg framework we are using mysql as backend. I have no idea how to start with it. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to perform a similar task recently and came up with [this script](http://pastebin.com/GPLBkgrQ).. maybe it can help you